# dropdown menu fly upwards

Tags: css

I made a css drop down menu, which fades in/out the sub-menu.

However, I'd like to change the effect to fade in and fly upwards, like here: 
http://css3menu.com/paradox-amethyst.html

How could that be done?

Right now I have the following html and css:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Photos</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Zoo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sky</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pie</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Zoo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sky</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pie</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #444;
}

ul.menu > li {
  float: left;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul.menu a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
}

ul.menu > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

ul.menu li ul > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 00px;
    left: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

.menu li:hover {
    background: maroon;
}

.menu li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5b5hckjh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can pull it off pretty easy:

- children `<ul>`s that are initially hidden, and when you hover over their parents, theyll show up, give em some space from the top, like top: 200px;
- then on hover, reduce that top space, to say 100%, for the direct children, so they'll offset from the top by 100%(the height of the navbar), and the subchildren, top: 0, so they'll fall in line with the they parents.

Check out the **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/o59kj2s7/3/)** or the snippet bellow:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #444;
}
ul.menu > li {
  float: left;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
}
ul.menu a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}
ul.menu > li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  /*this is the offset from the top, play around with it, pixel percentage what ever works best for you*/
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul.menu li ul > li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  /*this is the offset from the top, play around with it, pixel percentage what ever works best for you*/
  left: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.menu li:hover {
  background: maroon;
}
/*the direct children*/

.menu li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 100%;
}
/*the secondary children*/

.menu li li:hover > ul {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Photos</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Zoo</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sky</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Pie</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Zoo</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sky</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Pie</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hacky... use [CSS animation instead](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp), because that's what it's made for. top/left/etc. are for positioning/laying elements out, not animating them.

Comment: @DaveLunny indeed those props are for positioning elements, however I don't understand whats hacky about transitioning em. If I say top some value for initial state, then I say top another value for hover state, and yet another value on active state, it should work out properly. If browser support allows it, it should be able to transition between all these top values.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the CSS [transition](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_transitions.asp) property. You put this on the element (not it's hover state), and then set the top/left/etc. property that you want that element to start from (so for you you want the submenu to start from lower than the main menu bar). The in the `:hover` declaration you put the position where you want the transition to end (so for you this is right beneath the menu bar).

You should also look into [CSS 2D Tranforms](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) as they will allow you to move stuff around without relying on adding `position: absolute` to elements (because top/left/right animating is hacky and the W3C way to do things is through CSS animations, a la the `transform` property).

[Here's your jsfiddle (working) back](http://jsfiddle.net/Loezcyg5/)